# class Vector2 final : shared_ptr<Vector2> correct or not (Updated!)

Tags: c++, c++11

The reason of doing is that I want to force all objects to be a smart pointer when using this class. Thus, I can save some codes like

```
class Vector2 final : shared_ptr<Vector2>
{
...
inline shared_ptr<Vector2> getVector2(); //--> inline Vector2 getVector2();
...
inline static float dot(const shared_ptr<Vector2> a, const shared_ptr<Vector2> b); //--> inline static float dot(const Vector2 a, Vector2 b);
}
```

Is it correct?
if yes, is it the best practice?
if no, what is the best one?

==================================================================================

maybe I use another example

```
class Sprite
{
private:
Vector2* pPosition;
shared_ptr<Vector2> position;

Image* pBackground;
shared_ptr<Image> background;
};
```

Let me explain why i need the reference count.
When I update the position or background, I need to handle the delete operation before assigning the new value.

how about this one

```
inline static shared_ptr<Vector2> add(const Vector2* a, const Vector2* b)
```

this returns a result which may or may not be used before exiting the function. Then I need to delete manually if it is not used.

code saving means
1. no need delete the object manually
2. dont need to care whether it is shared_ptr or Vector2*. because I want to standardize to be one type

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand how that would save you anything. Why do your vectors need to be reference-counted at all? That is really expensive for something you fundamentally don't need, which complicates the semantics of your code and just makes readers go WTF.

The question is not whether `vector2` should *be* a shared pointer, or whether it should be wrapped in a shared pointer. There is no reason for doing either.

Answer (score 3):

I think your design is pretty awful. It is as though you want to have Java lifetimes or something.

You need to design with separation of concerns in mind.

you function `dot` should not care how the lifetime of Vector2 is managed, just take the Vector2 objects in by reference, and where you have them wrapped in `std::shared_ptr`s then defreference them before use.

In the same vain, your Vector2 objects should have no notion of how it's lifetime will be managed.